# fill in a HTML table with all days of month and date table from postgresql (javascript)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, postgresql, axios

I don't understand how to use generate_series to populate an HTML table where the 'key' of `<tr>` is the days of the month depending on the month and year that is selected with an `<input type='month'>`.

For now (thanks to the answers I got right here), I generated the query that only brings me the days of the month and year when I select it in the select month.

Something like this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM (
    SELECT
        folio,
        fecha,
        extract(month FROM fecha) = $3 AS mes,
        EXTRACT(YEAR FROM fecha) = $4 AS anio,
        temperatura
    FROM
        medicion) m
WHERE
    mes = TRUE
    AND anio = TRUE
ORDER BY
    fecha ASC
```

And got this in the HTML table:

| fecha | temperatura |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-03-04 | 60 |
| 2022-03-07 | 50 |
| 2022-03-09 | 70 |

But I need something like this:

| fecha | temperatura |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-03-01 | 0 |
| 2022-03-02 | 0 |
| 2022-03-03 | 0 |
| 2022-03-04 | 60 |
| 2022-03-05 | 0 |
| 2022-03-06 | 0 |
| 2022-03-07 | 50 |
| 2022-03-08 | 0 |
| 2022-03-09 | 70 |
| 2022-03-10 | 0 |

with all days and different for each month.

Comment: What does the output of the query look like?

Comment: with 5 columns, mes and anio are booleans (thats why in clause where is mes = true and anio = true)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
SELECT
    t.dt,
    coalesce(temperatura, 0)
FROM
    generate_series('03/01/2022'::timestamp, (('03/01/2022'::timestamp + interval '1 month') - interval '1 day'), '1 day') AS t (dt)
LEFT JOIN 
    medicion ON t.dt = medicion.fecha;
```

This assumes `medicion.fecha` is a `date` field. Also you would need to build the start date for the `generate_series()` from the `input` values to enter into the function, for instance $3/01/$4